# Mudar cor da divisória

Tags: css

Como consigo mudar a cor de uma Divisória "hr" "

---

"
Tentei os seguintes códigos na aba CSS do arquivo:

```css
.hr{
    color: #29303b;
}

hr{
    color: #29303b;
}
```

Comment: Olá, da uma olhada neste material, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp

Comment: Bruno, a propriedade `color` só se aplica a textos. No caso do HR você usaria a propriedade `border-color`.

Answer (score 2):

É só mudar a cor  do `border-color: #sua-cor;`  Veja o exemplo abaixo.

Vc ainda pode varia o `border-style` se quiser uma linga diferente...

```css
hr {
  border-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<hr>

<br>

<hr style="border-style: dotted;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Um workaround do stack gringo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382023/changing-the-color-of-an-hr-element

```
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```